# Using HTTP vs raw TCP to communicate between app and backend

Tags: node.js, mongodb, http, tcp

I am new to full stack app development. I have an iOS app which will communicate with the backend server (primarily node.js/MongoDB) via JSON. I know most apps use HTTP POST/GET to send receive data but I was wondering if I can reduce the HTTP overhead of sending/receiving data if I use a raw TCP connection and use my own lightweight protocol to communicate over that connection. What are the drawbacks of not using HTTP in this case?

Answer (score 1):

HTTP(S) clients are easier to use from a programmer's point of view; using TCP streams is more work in most languages; you'd have to do error and connection handling yourself.

Also, you will have to care about transport security yourself while most HTTPS clients and servers come with extended options for authentication and encryption.

Answer (score 1):

1. **You are reinventing the wheel** and will need to put a lot of effort into functionality well covered by existing implementations, some of which are refined for years by now. It is to doubt that you will achieve the same stability while retaining your *assumed* performance advantage. And not only do you have to write the code, but maintain it as well.
2. **Chances are you will do something wrong while reinventing said wheel** If you have to ask this question, you most likely lack the skills to implement a proper protocol. Even for highly experienced developers, it is not easy to properly implement authentication and authorization alone. Security through obscurity does not count ;) And that is only the top of the iceberg. Error handling, session and connection maintenance come to my mind. And *still* we are only at the top of the iceberg.
3. **You do premature optimization, which is the root of all evil**, according to [Donald Knuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth):

   > We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%."

   Your application logic is more likely to be the bottleneck than battle tested HTTP implementations.